# Swift UI on iOS 14 beta (1 to 3) not assigning new object to @State property

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14, xcode12

On iOS 13 I used to use optional `@State` properties to adapt views. In my case, the presented view would either create a new object (an assignment) if the state that is passed into it is nil, or edit the assignment if an assignment was passed in. This would be done in the action block of a Button and it worked beautifully.

On iOS 14 / Xcode 12 this no longer seems to work. Given the following code which creates a new assignment and passes it into the editor view when the user taps a "New Assignment" button, the value of `assignment` remains nil. Is anyone else experiencing similar behaviour?

```
struct ContentView: View {
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
        @State var assignmentEditorIsPresented = false
        @State var assignment: Assignment? = nil
        var Body: some View {
                [...]
                Button("New Assignment", action: {
                        self.assignment = Assignment(context: context)
                        self.assignmentEditorIsPresented = true
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: assignmentEditorIsPresented) {
                        [...]
                }
        }
}
```

I'm at a complete loss. This has been an issue for me since beta 1 and is present up to the current beta 3. As a workaround, I've been displaying the description of the object in a hidden Text view which fixes the problem:

```
Text("\(assignment?.description ?? "")")
    .hidden()
```

It seems to work maybe 50% of the time but is less than ideal. I just hope this is a bug and not a design change. Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: Well, State is designed to update view, if state is not used in (or does not affect) view it is natural to ignore it or even drop (for optimisation purpose). I think your use-case can be refactored. Would you show more code with both new/edit cases?

Comment: I would except that this is just one example where this happens. I’ve tested with a blank project where the state is a simple bool that presents a sheet and I have the same issue. Plus this code worked perfectly fine in Xcode 11.